# How does Roxygen to handle infix binary operators (eg. %in%)?

Tags: r, roxygen, roxygen2

As a simple, concrete example:

```
#' Inverse Value Matching
#' 
#' Complement of \code{%in%}. Returns the elements of \code{x} that are
#' not in \code{y}.
#' @usage x %nin% y
#' @param x a vector
#' @param y a vector
#' @export
"%nin%" <- function(x, y) {
  return( !(x %in% y) )
}
```

However, when I attempt to build a package the function seems to be ignored and no documentation is generated.

There seems to be a one-line blurb about binary infix functions at http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Documenting-functions, but I am having a hard time parsing it, and what it would imply for Roxygen documentation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to escape the `%`s in the usage section.  Also, I think you may need to specify an `rdname`

```
#' Inverse Value Matching
#' 
#' Complement of \code{%in%}. Returns the elements of \code{x} that are
#' not in \code{y}.
#' @usage x \%nin\% y
#' @param x a vector
#' @param y a vector
#' @export
#' @rdname nin
"%nin%" <- function(x, y) {
  return( !(x %in% y) )
}
```

---

Here is a function I have in a personal package.  I don't think I've ever actually used the function, but `roxygenize` does create a help file and the package passes `R CMD check`.

```
#' percent in
#' 
#' calculate the percentage of elements of \code{table} that are in \code{x}
#' 
#' @param x vector or NULL: the values to be matched
#' @param table vector or NULL: the values to be matched against
#' @return percentage of elements of \code{x} that are in \code{table}
#' @author gsee
#' @usage x \%pctin\% table
#' @examples
#' letters[1:10] %pctin% letters[1:3] # 30% of the second arg ar in the first
#' @export
#' @rdname PctIn
"%pctin%" <- function(x, table) length(x[x %in% table])/length(x)
```

Comment: @hadley, without it I get a NOTE `prepare_Rd: PctIn.Rd:4-6: Dropping empty section \usage`.  Aside from the NOTE, it does seems to work.

Comment: Oh hmmm, I guess that's an escaping issue.  I need to finish of roxygen3 and then merge it back into roxygen2.

Comment: grapes in the description also need escaping

Answer (score 1):

I've had a hard time with `roxygen` (speaking of `roxygen` not `roxygen2`) and infix operators. Here's what worked with my setup (`R` 2.15.1, `roxygen` 0.1-3).

First solution: edit the `Rd` file of every infix operator (should be `grapes ... grapes.Rd`) and escape with a baskslash every `%` in the `\alias`, `\usage` and `\name`parts.

Second solution: specify the tags @name and @usage in the documentation of the infix operator and escape the `%`. Here's an example:

```
##' Concatenates two strings
##'
##' @name \%+\%
##' @usage \%+\%(x, y)
##' @title Concatenation operator.
##' @param a String.
##' @param b String.
##' @return Same as paste0(a, b).
"%+%" <- function(a, b) paste(a, b, sep = "")
```