# roxygen2 documentation of binary operators - including examples causes warning or error on check

Tags: r, documentation, r-package, roxygen2, binary-operators

I try to include binary operators in my R packge and of course want to document them properly.
After stuying [How does Roxygen to handle infix binary operators (eg. %in%)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13829961/how-does-roxygen-to-handle-infix-binary-operators-eg-in) I tried the accepted solutions variant, but I have a question.
If I replicate this in a 1:1 manner and want to apply that for my own package, and apply @GSee's approach then this works as long as I don't bring in the @examples tag. Strangely @example works, but drops a warning during the package check procedure in RStudio.

Here is what I tried:
first example without @example or @examples: no issue

```
#' @title
#' Inverse Value Matching
#'
#' @description
#' Complement of \code{%in%}. Returns the elements of \code{x} that are
#' not in \code{y}.
#'
#' @usage x \%nin\% y
#'
#' @param x a vector
#' @param y a vector
#'
#' @export
#' @rdname nin
#'
#' @export
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
"%nin%" <- function(x, y) {
  return( !(x %in% y) )
}
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

now with @example, passes the check but drops a warning.

```
#' @title
#' Inverse Value Matching
#'
#' @description
#' Complement of \code{%in%}. Returns the elements of \code{x} that are
#' not in \code{y}.
#'
#' @usage x \%nin\% y
#'
#' @param x a vector
#' @param y a vector
#'
#' @export
#' @rdname nin
#'
#' @export
#' @example c(1:3) \%nin\% c(3:5)
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
"%nin%" <- function(x, y) {
  return( !(x %in% y) )
}
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

finally with @examples, fails the check

```
#' @title
#' Inverse Value Matching
#'
#' @description
#' Complement of \code{%in%}. Returns the elements of \code{x} that are
#' not in \code{y}.
#'
#' @usage x \%nin\% y
#'
#' @param x a vector
#' @param y a vector
#'
#' @export
#' @rdname nin
#'
#' @export
#' @examples 
#' c(1:3) \%nin\% c(3:5)
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
"%nin%" <- function(x, y) {
  return( !(x %in% y) )
}
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The issue is that you escaped the `%` in the examples section too.

Comment: I tried this out before, but just using %nin% also results in an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after spending a day with it, the solution  :) .

The tag @export must be followed by the operator name in double quoutes, and as @stefan pointed out, the \ were superflous.
Thanks, and enjoy the solution for your projects.

```
#' @title
#' Inverse Value Matching
#'
#' @description
#' Complement of \code{%in%}. Returns the elements of \code{x} that are
#' not in \code{y}.
#'
#' @usage x \%nin\% y
#'
#' @param x a vector
#' @param y a vector
#'
#' @export "%nin%"
#' @examples
#' Test::`%nin%`(c(1:3), c(3:5)) # result: 1 2
#' c(1:3) %nin% c(3:5)
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
"%nin%" <- function(x, y) {
  return( !(x %in% y) )
}
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```